# How can I reset equation numbering in each subsection*?

Tags: numbering, unnumbered-sections

I am a lyx user, and made a document using subsection*(unnumbered subsection).
I want to reset equation numbering each subsection and tried several methods, but all of them did not work.

What I tried(I tried adding below in the document-setting-Preamble):

1.

```
\makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{equation}{subsection}
    \makeatother
```

2. 

```
 \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
```

3. 

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}    
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
```

How I want to show: without part number, section number, just (number) only. like below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the equation counter can be reset at each new subsection with `\numberwithin`, like in your second trial. However, this does not work when the subsection counter is not incremented.

Another simple method is to renew the usual `\subsection` command to reset the `equation` counter before calling the old command.

Here's a complete example of this method.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
    \oldsubsection%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection*{A first subsection}

\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\subsection*{A second subsection}

\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \kappa T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanna reset the numbering. In your example, I want to put (1), instead of (2), in the second equation.

Comment: @user14261785 Wow indeed, I'm sorry. I guess I misread my own example! I'll modify my answer in a bit.

Comment: @user14261785 Done!

Comment: Thank you, you're so great!